# how to create dynamic inputs using ng-repeat and $index

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to iterate over array of `questions`. But I need to attach radio button answers to each question.
In this case I need to add different `ng-model`s for each answer.
I tried the code below but it didn't work.

Is this the correct way of using `$index` of the `ng-repeat`?

```
<li class="fields" ng-repeat="question in questions">
    <p>question:{{question.title}}</p>
    <div class="radio-buttons">
        <input type="radio" id="radio01" value="0" ng-model="answer[$index]" checked="checked"/>
        <label for="radio01"><span></span>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio02" value="1" ng-model="answer[$index]"/>
        <label for="radio02"><span></span>No</label>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? This looks like it should put all answers (0/1) in an `answer` array. Or maybe you want `ng-model="question.answer"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to do it like this `modelname{{$index}}`

```
 <li class="fields" ng-repeat="question in questions">
        <p>question:{{question.title}}</p>
        <div class="radio-buttons">
            <input type="radio" id="radio01" value="0" ng-model="answer{{$index}}" checked="checked"/>
            <label for="radio01"><span></span>Yes</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio02" value="1" ng-model="answer{{$index}}"/>
            <label for="radio02"><span></span>No</label>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: dont forget to accept the answer if it works :D @ahmdabos

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it via square bracket notation too if that pleases you aesthetically more:

```
<li class="fields" ng-repeat="(i, question) in questions">
  <p>question:{{question.title}}</p>
  <div class="radio-buttons">
    <input type="radio" id="radio01" value="0" ng-model="answer[i]" checked="checked"/>
    <label for="radio01"><span></span>Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio02" value="1" ng-model="answer[i]"/>
    <label for="radio02"><span></span>No</label>
  </div>
</li>
```

Also to note, models are better when expressed as dot models. So for example:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="answer[i]" />
```

Would be better as:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="models.answer[i]" />
```

Then in your controller this makes it simple to list all the models via the object 'models', rather than finding out how many answer[i] models there are.